# Concatenated files put into main.js just keeps stacking instead of clearing the file then adding the code

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat

I'm trying to compile all my scripts into a single `main.js` file which I can then link to my index file. Problem is that all my script files are being concatenated and then just **added** to the `main.js` file, so if I save 3 times, I will basically have 3 copies of all my scripts concatenated and put in the `main.js` file.

I would like to either delete the `main.js` file each time I save and then run the concatenation, or just clean the file before adding the contents. Now if I try to delete the file using the `del` module, I receive an error stating that I can't delete files out of the working directory without forcing this action. I would like to avoid forcing this if possible.

I feel that there must be a more elegant way of doing this..

Here's my script task:

```
// Concat and compile our JS into a minified dist file
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('../app/public/assets/scripts/**/*.js')
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    //.pipe(del(['../app/public/assets/scripts/main.js'])) <-- Doesn't work without forcing
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../app/public/assets/scripts'))
    .pipe(gulpif(flags.build, gulp.dest('../app/dist/assets/scripts')))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulpif(flags.build, gulp.dest('../app/dist/assets/scripts')))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Finished compiling scripts' }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like this (very simplified :) ):

```
var PARAMS = {
    destPath: 'build',
    js: [
        'src/js/test1.js',
        'src/js/test2.js',
        // ecc...
    ],
    // other
};

var TARGETS = {
    dest: 'main.js', // dest file

    extra: [
        // This files are inclued only in .bundle.min.js version
        // extra file here
    ],

    js: [
        'src/js/test1.js',
        'src/js/test2.js',
        // ecc...
    ]
};

gulp.task('connect', function() {
    return connect.server({
        livereload: true,
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: 8000
    });
});

gulp.task('reload', ['build'], function () {
    return gulp.src(['sandbox/**/*.html'])
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('watch', ['connect', 'build'], function () {
    var src = [];
    // other
    src = src.concat(PARAMS.js);
    return gulp.watch(src, ['reload']);
});

gulp.task('clean', function (done) {
    return del(['build'], done);
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function () {
    return gulp.src(target.js);
        .pipe(concat(target.dest))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(PARAMS.destPath))  // Plain

        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.js' }))  // Minified
        .pipe(gulp.dest(PARAMS.destPath))

        .pipe(addsrc(target.extra))
        .pipe(order(target.extra))
        .pipe(concat(target.dest))
        .pipe(rename({ extname: '.bundled.min.js' }))  // Bundled
        .pipe(gulp.dest(PARAMS.destPath));
});

gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

Comment: This happens on watch task though and not build, the build is no problem but I need to concat on every watch so I never have to include multiple files.

Comment: I edited the answer with the watch task. This helps? sorry but then I did not understand very well the problem :)

Comment: The problem is that the main.js file isn't being emptied before the new code comes in. So you get duplicated code in the file. And your answer doesn't seem to deal with that problem

Comment: in my code on each change (watc have ['connect', 'build'] deps ) is performed a build and a build depends on a clean...so you don't have duplicate code in the main.js